# Is it possible to re-load templates in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have written a custom template loader, and templates may change during the lifetime of a server. As I understand it, the first time a template is loaded it is parsed into the in-memory node-tree and thereafter it is cached.

Is it possible to invalidate this caching by issuing a command to say 'unload this template so it is re-loaded next time'? Or can my template loader take care of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

> the first time a template is loaded it is parsed into the in-memory node-tree and thereafter it is cached

is not true. Templates are only cached if `loaders` is not specified and the key `TEMPLATES -> OPTIONS['debug']` is True. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader) says:

> **class cached.Loader**
>
> This loader is automatically enabled if **OPTIONS['loaders']** isn’t specified and **OPTIONS['debug']** is **False** (the latter option defaults to the value of DEBUG).

So, in answer to your question, if you're using a custom loader, templates are not cached by default.

Comment: Cool. I thought that might be what the `django.template.loaders.cached.Loader` was for but wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you're doing something you don't want to be doing. That said...

The way to get around the caching is to bypass the loader system and load the template from file manually:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Template, RequestContext

# open the template file and save it to a string in memory
template_as_string = open('/path/to/template/file.html').read()

# make any dynamic modifications to your template string here,
# including saving back to file if necessary

# get and render a Django template, return an HttpResponse
template = Template(template_as_string)
return HttpResponse(template.render(context=RequestContext(request, {
    # variables to be sent to the template for rendering
})
```

Comment: Trust me, there's a good reason for a custom template loader (not getting templates from the filesystem). And these are not changing inside a view function.

Comment: "there is a good reason" is unhelpful. If we don't know what exactly you're trying to do, it's hard to give you sound advice / help. The loading from the filesystem is not really the point; the point I'm making is to load the template as string directly if it's fundamentally mutable.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think that 'doing something you don't want to be doing' was central to the discussion. What I am doing is loading templates from a database with a custom naming scheme. Beyond the template loader this is transparent to views when they load templates. These templates may change in the database, and when they do, that change must be reflected in the loaded templates. I can raise an event when the template changes FWIW.

Comment: Would http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dbtemplates help you out any? I've implemented this on one project and it worked very well.